# How do I insert sigma superscript hat and subscript beta 1 hat?

Tags: math-mode

[image: What I want to write]

I tried the following code with a badly rendered result:

```
\hat{\sigma_{\hat{\beta_1}}}
```

Is there a better way to render it like the image shown?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 8):

The `\hat` macro is designed to be placed over a single character. Hence, you should write

```
\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta}_1}
```

Observe that the arguments of both `\hat` instructions now consist of a single character (`\sigma` and `\beta`, resp.).

For an extra touch of (typographic!) class, consider "snugging up" the `\hat{\sigma}` and `\hat{\beta}_1` terms by starting the subscript term with a `\!` (negative thinspace) instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta}_1} \quad \hat{\sigma}_{\!\hat{\beta}_1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: One could do `\widehat{\sigma_{\widehat{\beta_1}}}`, but the output is painful to the eye. Even if the hat denotes the action of a function, it is customary to ignore the subscripts in order to apply the hat `\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta}_{1}}`; similarly `\bar{z}_1` for “the conjugate of zee sub one” is perfectly acceptable and `\overline{z_1}` not really necessary (it may be when dealing with beginners).

Comment: @egreg - I strive not to create output that's painful to the eye... I may not always succeed, though! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta_1}}
```

This will put the first hat above the sigma, and the second hat is just above the beta_1.
-- update: Mico mentions the second hat should be above the beta only, thanks to Mico.

Comment: The OP's screenshot does not suggest that the second "hat" should be placed above both `\beta` and `1`.